# Equivalente da String usando variaveis - Python 3.x

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Qual seria o equivalente da string :

```
values = """
  {
   "exchange_code": "PLNX",
   "exchange_market": "BTC/USDT"
  }
"""
```

O qual o resultado é :

> '\n   {\n    "exchange_code": "PLNX",\n    "exchange_market": "BTC/USDT"\n   }\n'

entrando "PLNX" e "BTC/USDT" como variaveis, estou tentando algumas variacoes como a abaixo mas nao consigo replicar o resultado acima :

```
def equi_string(exchange,market):
  values = """
    {
     "exchange_code": """+exchange+""",
     "exchange_market": """+market+"""
    }
  """
  return values
```

> '\n    {\n     "exchange_code": PLNX,\n     "exchange_market": BTC/USDT\n    }\n  '

Esse por exemplo falta "" em PLNX e BTC/USDT

Como eu faco para a string retornar exatamente o primeiro exemplo ?

Comment: Experimenta usar o modulo json. https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html . Provavelmente é uma string no format json

Answer (score 0):

Se queres apenas criar a string nesse formato, tente usar o caractere "\" para escapar as aspas:

```
def equi_string(exchange,market):
  values = """
    {
     "exchange_code": \""""+exchange+"""\",
     "exchange_market": \""""+market+"""\"
    }
  """
  return values
```

Uma outra opção é utilizar o format, você só precisa escapar as chaves "{" e "}":

```
def equi_string(exchange,market):
   values = """
     {{
      "exchange_code": "{}",
      "exchange_market": "{}"
     }}
   """
   return values.format(exchange,market)
```

Mas se você precisar criar mais objetos nesse mesmo formato mais complexos que esse, recomendo utilizar o JSON.